# MRJob - Limit Number of Task Attemps

Tags: emr, mrjob

In MyJob, how do you limit the number of task attempts (if a task fails)?

I have long running tasks (have increased the timeout, accordingly), but I want the job to end after 2 failed attempts at the same task, rather than 4-5.

I couldn't find anything like this in the docs:

http://mrjob.readthedocs.org/en/latest//en/latest/guides/configs-reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For map jobs, you can set `mapreduce.map.maxattempts` in Hadoop 2. For reduce jobs, set `mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts` ([source](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)).
The equivalents in Hadoop 1 are: `mapred.map.max.attempts` and `mapred.reduce.max.attempts`.

If you are using a conf file in MRJob, you can set this as:

```
runners:
    emr:
        jobconf:
            mapreduce.map.maxattempts: 2
```